# Deriving Phone number from a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have some vectors as below:

I converted all characters, Special characters into X

```
xxxxxx18002514919xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx24XXXXXX7

xxxxxx9000012345xxxxxxxxxxxxx34567xxxxxxxxxxxxx1800XXXXXX7
```

How can I derive only 11 digit or 10 digit phone number from the above strings in R

My Desired Output is:
For first string:  18002514919
For second string:  9000012345

Comment: So you just want to extract the numbers? Take a look at `?regex`

Comment: Can you put your desirable output for the question, In general regular expression is used for such problems.

Comment: Try something like `regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d{10,}", x))` if `x` is your string.

Comment: @Dason Not all the numbers, that the phone numbers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Silly me I should have read more carefully ;)

Comment: I added desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr` to solve your problem, There is function called str_extract_all to extract the phone number as desired.

The regex: 
`\\d` --> represent number,
`{n,m}` --> curly braces are for matching the times of number. Here n is applied for minimum no of matches and m is maximum number of numbers for the match. Since you want to match a phone number whose length between 10 and 11. n becomes 10 and m becomes 11.

```
X <- c("xxxxxx18002514919xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx24XXXXXX7","xxxxxx9000012345xxxxxxxxxxxxx34567xxxxxxxxxxxxx1800XXXXXX7")
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(X,"\\d{10,11}")
```

**Answer:**

```
> str_extract_all(X,"\\d{10,11}")
[[1]]
[1] "18002514919"

[[2]]
[1] "9000012345"
```

If you are sure that one scalar would contain only one string of phone number then use `str_extract`.

```
> str_extract(X,"\\d{10,11}")
[1] "18002514919" "9000012345"
```